# Multiple Modal Timers running continuously without the delay

Tags: python, scripting

I am new to blender and i need to visualise linear transformations. I am using this piece of code to create a timer.

```
def mod (mid, label, timeout, callback, *args):

    class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
        bl_idname = mid
        bl_label = label

        _timer = None
        valid = True

        def modal(self, context, event):
            if not self.valid or event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
                self.cancel(context)
                return {'CANCELLED'}

            if event.type == 'TIMER':
                self.valid = callback(*args)

            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        def execute(self, context):
            wm = context.window_manager
            self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(timeout, context.window)
            wm.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

        def cancel(self, context):
            wm = context.window_manager
            wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)

    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)
```

so i am assuming `function callback (args...)` gets called every time after timeout seconds.

So overall i am creating a cube then creating two timers with different timeouts. one does a translation and other does Rotation. But the problem with the timers is that, instead of firing every timeout seconds it is firing continuously one after another without the timeout delay. Happens when multiple timers are present

```
mymesh =  makeCube () 

translateMatrix = mathutils.Matrix.Translation( mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 1)) )
rotationMatrix  = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(45.0), 3, "Z")

mod("wm.a", "a", 2,   transformation, mymesh, translateMatrix, True)
mod("wm.b", "b", 0.1, transformation, mymesh, rotationMatrix,  True)

bpy.ops.wm.a();
bpy.ops.wm.b();
```

Please Help me. Here is overall code.

```
import mathutils
import math 
import bpy
import bmesh

def clean():
    for i in bpy.data.objects:
        i.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.delete()

def mod (mid, label, timeout, callback, *args):

    class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
        bl_idname = mid
        bl_label = label

        _timer = None
        valid = True

        def modal(self, context, event):
            if not self.valid or event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
                self.cancel(context)
                return {'CANCELLED'}

            if event.type == 'TIMER':
                self.valid = callback(*args)

            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        def execute(self, context):
            wm = context.window_manager
            self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(timeout, context.window)
            wm.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

        def cancel(self, context):
            wm = context.window_manager
            wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)

    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)

def makeCube ():
    verts = [ (0, 0, 0), (0, 5, 0), (5, 5, 0), (5, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5), (0, 5, 5), (5, 5, 5), (5, 0, 5) ]
    faces = [ (0, 1, 2, 3), (7, 6, 5, 4), (0, 4, 5, 1), (1, 5, 6, 2), (2, 6, 7, 3), (3, 7, 4, 0) ]
    edges = []

    mymesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("supershape")
    myobject = bpy.data.objects.new("supershape",mymesh)

    myobject.location.x = 0
    myobject.location.y = 0
    myobject.location.z = 0

    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(myobject)

    mymesh.from_pydata(verts,edges,faces)
    mymesh.update(calc_edges=True)

    myobject.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME')

    return mymesh

def transformation (mesh, matrix, ret):

    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)

    #Modify the vertices of mesh
    for v in bm.verts:
        v.co = matrix * v.co

    # update mesh 
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    mesh.update (calc_edges = True)
    bm.free()
    return ret 

clean()                #remove all the objects
mymesh =  makeCube () 

translateMatrix = mathutils.Matrix.Translation( mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 1)) )
rotationMatrix  = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(45.0), 3, "Z")

mod("wm.a", "a", 2,   transformation, mymesh, translateMatrix, True)
mod("wm.b", "b", 0.1, transformation, mymesh, rotationMatrix,  True)

bpy.ops.wm.a();
bpy.ops.wm.b();
```

Comment: Confused as to what the question is here. Yes the timers run continously firing a `'TIMER'` event every `timeout` seconds.  Suggest looking into a frame change handler to do this. [see Handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.app.handlers.html) , or some other method like drivers, that utilize the animation system built into blender.

Comment: @batFINGER i am sorry, i wanted to say that instead of firing every timeout seconds it is firing continuously one after another without the timeout delay. Happens when multiple timers are present

Comment: Ok, recall another question about that. Would use one timer and give each callout a count (eg timer every 0.1 seconds,  rotate:1 translate:20) or as mentioned prior use a frame change handler.

Comment: May find [this useful too](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47663/how-to-handle-modal-operator-events-in-a-single-loop)

Comment: @batFINGER yes. its better to use single timer and figure out which functions to run. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, write up an answer with basics. Out of interest, why change local coords of every vert every tick,  could alternatively calculate object matrix each tick.   And to reiterate, consider using the animation system built in to blender. to tie in the state of your object to the frame number.  Will put up handler answer if you are interested.

Comment: @batFINGER I am learning 3D math and just wanted to visualise how objects are changing by applying different transformations, step by step. prior to this was using geogebra which was very slow.