# Blender game engine data extract

Tags: python, game-engine, command-line

i am trying to connect Blender game engine to a PLC(programable logic controller) so i can control a robot with blender game engine, i dont know where to start to take de bge data outside of blender, get the object rotation/speed/scale and variables data outside of blender to connect it to matlab or the python console in windows, where should i look?, what i need to learn to do this data extraction, i know how to use python scripting inside bge already, i just need to know how to begin extracting data outside of blender.

Comment: You could print the coordinates of the model inside BGE every 10ms by using an infinite loop with timers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python). This question is similar: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116059/multiple-modal-timers-running-continuously-without-the-delay

Answer (score 1):

You have to comunicate to your plc by a python socket (import socket) and stripe whatever you are sending from your local port (arduino) or the local port on you have the plc.